# Opencart remove demo catalog

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

when paste my web site link to Facebook time line the demo banner image appear in the preview although i removed them
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use facebook open graph markup. Using this you can set title, description and image. To set an image, use this

```
<meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE_URL" />
```

Use those tags inside `<head>`. May be helpful, try this [open graph markup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup)

Comment: where to put it in opencart

Comment: I already mentioned that you need to use all open graph markup inside <head></head>. So modify your header.php and place your code there.

Answer (score 1):

**Facebook Markup for sharing in facebook**

Facebook has made its own markup language to understand content in your webpage.
This makes sharing in Facebook managed, beautiful and easy. For this you have to add following tags inside head tag of your webpage.

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="Your current page's url" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="content type" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="Title of your page or title you want to show in facebook" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="Short description what your webpage is about" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="url of your image to be shown in facebook" />
```

You can now share beautiful content in facebook.
Hope it helps.